# How to pull all product urls using liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to display all my product titles and URLs using.

```
        <ul>
        <h3>Products</h3>
        {% for product in collections.all.products %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ product.url }}">{{ product.title }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But it is only displaying the first 50 pages. How can I make it to show all my products

Comment: by default Shopify returns the first 50 records, you need to use the paginate to push the limit.

Comment: check more regarding paginate [Here](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/theme-tags#paginate)

Comment: Perfect! It's worked but I need the product name, Price, variation & product selected collection name
How can we do that?